# MS SQL Server работа с jdbc driver > Не удалось выполнить вход

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

пытаюсь подключиться к бд используя MS SQL Server как субд. Скачал и поставил драйвер, добавил его в проект. Задал url:

jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName=ApartmentsSystem;integratedSecurity=true;

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL);
```

При попытке подключения пишет:

Не удалось выполнить вход. Имя входа принадлежит недоверенному домену и не может использоваться в проверке подлинности Windows. ClientConnectionId:f9544554-eba8-4405-81e2-3194aa72295f

Может кто подсказать, в чем проблема? Может еще что настраивать надо в субд для работы драйвера?

Answer (score 0):

В общем integratedSecurity=true означает windows аутентификацию, я так понял там явно нужно задавать пользователя и пароль для аутентификации(по некоторым причинам, не хочу использовать windows аутентификацию), по этому использовал sql аутентификацию(integratedSecurity=false), прописал явно пользователя и пароль. И все порядке.